# Emacs Rinari won't load at startup

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs, rinari

Hey, I wanted to try out some rails. And since I don't want to use any fancy IDE. I thought I could try rails out using emacs with Rinari. Anyway I got some problem which I couldn't find any solution on google for it.

Basically I have a clean `.emacs` and I added the necessary lines for it

```
   ;; Interactively Do Things (highly recommended, but not strictly required)
   (require 'ido)
   (ido-mode t)

   ;; Rinari
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/home/stardust/rinari")
   (require 'rinari)
```

The only thing that's change is the location for where I extracted Rinari. When I try to open emacs with these changes I get this error. Anyone who might know what the problem is?

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/stardust/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, rinari

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the `~` in front of the path to Rinari is superfluous and should be removed.